# Generate random string from list of string in C#?

Tags: c#, random

Get 'n' random string from a Arraylist of string. Where n= number of string I want from the list it can be 1,2,3....?  Suppose that I have Array list of N Strings if I want to choose Random four strings without repetition. How can I do it? The code should be in C#. Though I have done this, but What is the best way?

Comment: You could put a little more effort into the question... Effectively what you are asking is how to generate a random number which you can then use to access a list?

Comment: Don't ask your assignment here :).

Comment: Can anyone please help me out

Comment: If you expect help, I suggest you to edit your question and reformulate it in a more specific manner.

I'm sure this way, you will obtain help without a doubt :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int myRandomIndex = 0;
        var myList = new List<string>(new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" });
        var results = new List<string>();
        var r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++)
        {
            myRandomIndex = r.Next(myList.Count);
            results.Add(myList[myRandomIndex]);
            myList.RemoveAt(myRandomIndex);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", results));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

To keep each chosen string unique (prevent duplicates) I remove it from the source list as it is used. You should also do a `myList = myList.Distinct()` before using the list, to make sure you don't have duplicates in it to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

[Shuffling](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html) @ Coding Horror

Comment: IT is really a coding horror. But I need a solution.